# Why does not equal computing line in `OpenLayers` with `ArcGIS` when i use measure control?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, openlayers-2

My map projection is: "EPSG:900913" ,Display projection is "EPSG:4326" and units is "m", however does not equal the length is calculated in `OpenLayers` with `ArcGIS`, in fact Openlayers show the length more than the actual length ***`when i use measure control`***.

For example:

```
the calculation length in ArcGIS is:26,072.443575
```

[image]

```
and in OpenLayers is: 3.0757.
```

[image]

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the coordinates of the line.

Comment: @Vince i edit my question.

Comment: If you're just clicking on the screen, graphical representation issues around pixel size and "twips" could more than explain the difference.

Comment: @Vince No, I just clicked on the line!

Comment: have you already set the option geodesic: true to your measure control?

Comment: @ThomasB Yes. but i use `DynamicMeasure` too, that dont have geodesic property.

Comment: do you mean https://github.com/jorix/OL-DynamicMeasure ? perhaps you can post a bit of your code...

Comment: @ThomasB Yes, I mean the same thing, also i have this problem in insertDirectionLength,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using DynamicMeasure( github.com/jorix/OL-DynamicMeasure )
you can also use `geodesic:true` to get better results:

```
var measureControls = {
        line: new OpenLayers.Control.DynamicMeasure(OpenLayers.Handler.Path)

    };

measureControls.line.geodesic=true;

measureControls.line.activate();
```

I just forked the repository and added an option to switch `geodesic:true` on interactively:

http://rawgit.com/neogis-de/OL-DynamicMeasure/geodesic/examples/measure-dynamic.html

Comment: i have same problem in insertDirectionLength, How to resolve this problem???

Comment: you better post this as a seperate question

Comment: I asked this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167673/why-does-not-equal-length-of-line-in-direction-length-with-length-of-line-in-mea?noredirect=1#comment249639_167673, please reply it!