# Why does not equal length of line in DIRECTION/LENGTH with length of line in MEASURING in OpenLayers 2.13?

Tags: openlayers-2, measurements

My map projection is: "EPSG:900913", display projection is "EPSG:4326" and units is "m", however does not equal the length in **`Direction/length`** with the length is calculated in **`measuring`** in OpenLayers, in fact OpenLayers show the length more than the actual length when I use measure control. I've set the option geodesic: true to my measure control.

For example:

```
the enter length is: 100m
```

[image: direction/length]

```
the length after measuring is: 85.29m
```

[image: length of line]

Define measure control:

```
 measureLine = new OpenLayers.Control.DynamicMeasure(OpenLayers.Handler.Path);
measureLine.geodesic = true;

function insertDirectionLength(drawType) {
    var values = parseInput(
    window.prompt(
            "Enter direction and length offset values for new point (e.g. '-45, 10')", "direction, length"
    )
     );
     if (values != null) {
         var controlKey,key;
         for (key in controls) {
             controlKey = controls[key];
             if (drawType == key) {
                  controlKey.insertDirectionLength(values[0], values[1]);
             } 
         }
     }
 }
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You're using [Mercator for length](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/03/05/measuring-distances-and-areas-when-your-map-uses-the-mercator-projection/) and comparing with great circle on a sphere?

Comment: Similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48142/which-area-measurement-to-trust-the-same-polygon-in-googleearth-v-arcgis (which is itself a duplicate)

Comment: @Vince No, My question is different!!!

Comment: If you edit the question to contain the exact vales used (lon,lat in addition to bearing and distance), and the exact coordinate values of the resuling geometry, you might find that the issue is the same.

Comment: Let me guess--the line is around latitude +/-31.5 degrees?

Comment: Every time someone says `EPSG:900913` it makes @mkennedy eyes twitch. Please use code `EPSG:3857` instead.

Comment: @Mintx I also tried `EPSG:3857`, but did not differ.

Answer (score 0):

> My map projection is: "EPSG:900913" ,Display projection is "EPSG:4326"

I believe this is the crux of your problem. It looks like you are drawing in <s>EPSG:900913</s> EPSG:3857 and you are measuring in EPSG:4326.

The [Pseudo-Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator) projection is notoriously bad at calculating/drawing distances, so I would not use this projection for that kind of work.